# Why does click propagation seem to jump over the top element of the next stacking context?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's my example code:

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7);
  cursor: pointer;
}

img.overlay__first-child {
  position: fixed;
  top: -25px;
  right: -25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 3;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: green;
}

.overlay img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.overlay__second-child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="no-styling" onclick="console.log('no-styling')">
  <div class="overlay" onclick="console.log('overlay')">
    <img src="#" class="overlay__first-child" onclick="console.log('overlay__first-child')" />
    <img src="#" class="overlay__second-child" onclick="console.log('overlay__second-child')" />
  </div>

  <p onclick="console.log('p')">Content to create a scrollbar</p>
  <p onclick="console.log('p')">Content to create a scrollbar</p>
  <p onclick="console.log('p')">Content to create a scrollbar</p>
  <p onclick="console.log('p')">Content to create a scrollbar</p>
  <p onclick="console.log('p')">Content to create a scrollbar</p>
  <p onclick="console.log('p')">Content to create a scrollbar</p>
  <p onclick="console.log('p')">Content to create a scrollbar</p>
  <p onclick="console.log('p')">Content to create a scrollbar</p>
  <p onclick="console.log('p')">Content to create a scrollbar</p>
  <p onclick="console.log('p')">Content to create a scrollbar</p>
  <p onclick="console.log('p')">Content to create a scrollbar</p>
  <p onclick="console.log('p')">Content to create a scrollbar</p>
</div>
```

If I click on the `p` text that's behind the overlay, the log doesn't print `p`, but it does print `no-styling`. If I change the `p` tags into `button` tags, I see the same propagation jump. On the other hand, if I click directly on a `p` element, it logs `p` and `no-styling`, as expected. I've tested this on Firefox and Google Chrome and see the same results.

For clarification, I've added yellow dots to this screenshot to show locations I'm clicking:

[image]

Every yellow dot except the lowest prints `overlay__first-child` and `overlay__second-child`, if applicable; `overlay`; and `no-styling`, but none of these clicks prints `p`. The lowest dot prints `no-styling` and `p`.

Why does clicking on the overlay skip the `onclick` of the `p` tags?

Comment: Is that not what is expected? If you click, the toplevel element at that pixel gets the event. Any element that is being *covered* by that toplevel element does not receive the event. Maybe I misunderstand the question. I see nothing unusual happening in the snippet.

Comment: @trincot Sorry for answering a question with a question, but what is your definition of "covered"? I would consider `no-styling` to be just as covered as `p` is, yet `no-styling` receives the event. Someone might say it's because `no-styling` isn't *completely* covered by the overlay, but if you open the inspector, neither is the `p` element: its width extends past the text.

Comment: HTML elements have a front-to-back order: when two elements overlap, then one of them will be in front of the other. Only the front one receives the event if the click happens on a point that is shared by both. The effect of event bubbling is a separate mechanism, which follows the child-parent hierarchy to the top. Yes, the `p` element is wider, and that's why a click on that extent (not covered by the overlay) *will* arrive on the `p` element.

Comment: @trincot "Only the front one receives the event if the click happens on a point that is shared by both." Although I've only describe two scenarios in my description, neither are behaving as described. Where are you clicking that behaves like this? I'll upload a screenshot of where I'm clicking in a few minutes.

Comment: I click on the red area and get `overlay > no-styling`. It is normal that you don't see `p` in the output. I may misunderstand your question.  Maybe simplify to just two HTML elements? Is your question about event bubbling or about the target element that gets the event? Can you focus your question on either?

Comment: @trincot updated with screenshot

Comment: I see nothing unusual in that. The colored areas all represent front elements that cover the `p` elements which are *behind* these elements, so you cannot click the `p` elements *there*. Only where the `p` elements "stick out" from under those covering elements, can you click them.

Comment: @trincot That would make sense to me if it *didn't* print `no-styling` in those situations, but it does. Why don't the colored areas cover the `no-styling` element?

Comment: Because that is an ancestor element in the DOM hierarchy. This is the effect of event bubbling and has nothing to do with this front-to-back ordering.

Comment: @trincot ah ok. Earlier you said, `HTML elements have a front-to-back order: when two elements overlap, then one of them will be in front of the other. Only the front one receives the event if the click happens on a point that is shared by both.` Does this statement only apply to non-ancestor elements? BTW, these details are what I'm looking for in an answer.

Comment: That statement applies to the target element that receives the click event. If the event is a bubbling event (which is the case for click events), that event will bubble up via the DOM hierarchy up to the root of the document. But again that is a secondary effect that is unrelated to front-to-back ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different mechanisms going on here:

- The mechanism that determines which is the "front" element that will receive the click event
- The mechanism that bubbles a received element from an element to its ancestors in the DOM hierarchy.

The first mechanism takes the coordinates of the cursor (mouse) and, among the elements that have that point in their area, looks at the Z-order in which these elements are ordered (front-to-back ordering). This ordering is not necessarily related to the DOM hierarchy -- it can be completely different from it as it can be freely determined by CSS. In your example case the overlay element is rendered in front of the `p` elements. That means that if the click happens on a coordinate that is included in the overlay element, it is the overlay element that gets the initial click event, no matter whether there is also a `p` element that has that coordinate. Or, if the click happens outside the overlay area, but still on the area of a `p` element, it is that `p` element that gets the initial click event.

The second mechanism concerns event bubbling. Some events bubble, others don't. Click events bubble. Bubbling means that after the original target element received the click event, its ancestors -- according to the DOM hierarchy, irrespective where those elements are rendered -- also get a click event, up to the root element of the DOM hierarchy. NB: any of the handlers of the click event can cancel this bubbling, so it does not propagate further up the DOM hierarchy.

I think with these principles the behaviour of your example is explained.

Answer (score 1):

Alright the solution to this is to use bubbles and I shall show you how exactly, with an example:

```
const containerElement = document.querySelector('.container');
const containerChildElement = document.querySelector('.containerChild');

containerElement.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => console.log(target));
```

Alright so how this works is it adds an event listener to the parent element (containerElement) which is supposedly behind the child element, there is a concept called bubbles which basically says the event must bubble up through the DOM tree and goes through all the children, the event.target property will store the childElement if you click on the part where the child and parent are overlapping.

The code might be slightly hard to read if you aren't familar with destructuring, basically the `({ target })` part just means event.target.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the help! It appears you're answering the question, "How does event bubbling work?" Although understanding this is critical to my question, and it will help others who don't understand event bubbling, I think the key component I was missing was, "the event must bubble up through the DOM tree and goes through all the **parents**". Correct me if I'm wrong, though.

Comment: By the way, stackoverflow has a "code snippet" button that allows you to post examples you can run and modify. Here is the button to create one: https://imgur.com/a/oDFmo0y